# Wildly bowed bathroom wall behind sink install

Tags: bathroom, walls

I have a sink that I am putting in a bathroom. The wall, however, is extraordinarily bowed inward (concave). I don’t want to just pump it full of caulk and make it a day. I’d like it to look good. This is in an older house. Do you guys have any ideas what I could do to fix this and make it look nice?

[image]

---

It’s a 1/2 inch at its widest point. I hadn’t planned to add tile.

Comment: I see that you didn’t plan on tile, but is that a possibility? A mosaic tile on mesh, in particular, would allow you to put more thinset in the middle down low and feather that to not have an obvious gap at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a mirror sitting on coving tiles (the quarter round ones)...

Answer (score 0):

A tile backsplash would do a very good job of covering up the gap. Regular tiles are usually about 1/4", so that wouldn't be enough, but you can use cove base tiles for the row just above the sink (they're usually used on the bottom of a wall).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why the drywall bowed to the inside. It could be too thin for the span between the studs. Regardless, you now have two options: remove the drywall and install 1/2" drywall if the span is 16", or 5/8" if the distance between the studs is more. The second option is to use drywall joint compound to fix it. I'd go with the joint compound.

Comment: Could be that the wall is plaster, and not drywall, especially given that it's an "older house."  Still, a plaster skim coat could be the way to go.  Odds are there'll be a mirror above the sink, so the skim would only need to go up to the bottom of the mirror, where it could be tapered from "flat."